# Set Vuejs transition on elements to let appear others

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is not a problem but more a "how to" here.
Let's say I have this kind of template (`id` are just there to be clearer) :

```
<template>
  <div id="1" v-if="someCondition"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
</template>
```

When `someCondition` is false, only `div` with `id="2"` and `id="3"` will be rendered.
While I understand how to add a transition on the conditionnal element `id="1"` like this :

```
<template>
  <transition name="..."
    <div id="1" v-if="someCondition"></div>
  </transition>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
</template>
```

How can I make the two others divs (`id="2"` and `id="3"`) move smoothly to let the place to `id="1"` to appear and only after the place is there it can do its transition to appear (when `someCondition` becomes `true`)?

Because at the moment, `id="2"` and `id="3"` are moved down (or up if `id="1"` disappears because `someCondition` goes to `false` again) without any transition and it's quite ugly.

https://jsfiddle.net/nyaf2jxz/

Comment: Could you add a snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Sure I added a simple jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transition the `max-height` property to make it seem smoother:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleElement() {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#one {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
}

#three {
  background-color: green;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: opacity 1.5s 0.2s, max-height 1.5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: opacity 1.5s, max-height 0.8s 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition name="fade" duration="2000">
    <div id="one" v-if="show">
      This is conditional div
    </div>
  </transition>
  <div id="two">
    This is second div
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    This is third div
  </div>
  <button @click="toggleElement()">
    Toggle Element
  </button>
</div>
```

Just set it to be something higher than the `div` will ever be, in this case, `100px`.

If you have to account for `margin` and `padding` you can set them to 0 with a delay so you don't notice they've been changed:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleElement() {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#one {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
}

#three {
  background-color: green;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: opacity .5s, max-height .5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  transition: opacity .5s, max-height .5s, padding .1s .4s, margin .1s .4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition name="fade" duration="500">
    <div id="one" v-if="show">
      This is conditional div
    </div>
  </transition>
  <div id="two">
    This is second div
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    This is third div
  </div>
  <button @click="toggleElement()">
    Toggle Element
  </button>
</div>
```

Just make sure the duration and delay of the CSS transition adds up to the duration of the Vue transition.

Comment: Indeed it does what I asked for ! Nice ! However i give you here a more complete example of what I'm actually doing. It does a smooth transition indeed but at the end it still does this ugly quick move. Do you know why ? https://codepen.io/laurent-brisbois/pen/vYLMBRd try clicking on message/comment/answer buttons to toggle the form element. Click the same twice to make it disappear.

Comment: It's because of the `margin` and `padding` on `.v-form.logger-form`

Comment: No worries @Ibris, added an example snippet if you need it.